# subi una web a github pero en el navegador no se ven las imagenes . HTML CSS

Tags: html, web, imagen, github, repositorio

estoy aprendiendo a hacer páginas web, y lo a subi a github pages.

Mientras estaba trabajando en localhost, las imagenes que puse en en el index.hmtl se ven perfecto. luego arme mi repo en github, lo subi a pages, y se cargaron todos los archivos.. cuando accedo al link que me brinda github y la abro mediante un navegador, se ve la pagina pero sin las imagenes..

Revise los enlaces en el codigo creo que esta todo bien pero no se donde esta el problema. Visualizé la pagina desde dos navegadores -por las dudas-  Chrome y Firefox. nada.
ojala puedan orientarme porque busque videos, aquí tambien pero nada se parece a lo que me ocurre con mi pagina.
les dejo el enlace al repo ojala alguien pueda darme una mano
https://github.com/supertropia/restorecoffee.github.io

y esta es la pagina para acceder desde el navegador
https://supertropia.github.io/restorecoffee.github.io/

muchas muchas gracias

Comment: Cambia `/images/` por `images/` en los atributos `src=` de los elementos `<img>` de tu html

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente estés usando rutas privadas en lugar de rutas públicas en el src de tus etiquetas img, es decir puedes tener algo como /imagen o ./images, en ese caso solo deberías quitar la / o ./ Quedando solo images/archivo.extension.